# Python3 trouble with classes, passing variables

Tags: python-3.x, oop, object, beautifulsoup

Practicing/trying to learn beautiful soup and working with objects/classes.

I created a basic web scraper that could scrape a page on one website but I'm trying to seperate everything so the scraper will recognise which website it is from the url and scrape automatically.

The problem is I don't know how to pass the website name across my objects nicely. I tried using the variable 'website' but I'm not sure how to actually use it.

There are bits before this but this is the part I'm stuck on.

```
class AllProductsPage:
def __init__(self, page_content):
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')

@property
def products(self, website):
    store_product_locator = ProductLocator.(website)
    return [ProductParser(e) for e in self.soup.select(store_product_locator)]

class ProductLocator:
    website_to_scrape = "div.product-item.js-product-data"
```

I would like to be able to have multiple "website_to_scrape" that the locators would be used automatically depending on what the "website" variable was, such as "website = website_to_scrape_7"

Should I just make the website variable a global variable across all classes? Is that a normal thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end, just passed the website as a parameter into the ProductLocator and put the locators into a dictionary which I loop over and compare against the website input.

I can now add more locators and it automatically uses the right locator for each website when parsing.